# Spark: Reporting Total, and Available Memory of the Cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing, amazon-emr, elastic-map-reduce

I'm running a Spark job on an Amazon EMR; I would like to keep reporting the total, and free memory of the cluster from within the program itself.  Is there any method in Spark API which provides information about the cluster's memory?

Comment: `SparkContext.getExecutorMemoryStatus`  provides some information but the  [REST API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) is more advanced source of data and can be easily queried from the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spark.metrics.conf

How to use :
initialise spark.metrics.conf in your spark conf file

```
spark.metrics.conf = /path/to/metrics.properties
```

At the above path create ***metrics.properties*** file .In that file mention the parameters you want from the spark application, even you can specify the format and the interval.

Eg Here I am getting the data in CSV format in every 1 minute :

```
driver.sink.csv.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.CsvSink

# Polling period for the CsvSink
#*.sink.csv.period=1
# Unit of the polling period for the CsvSink
#*.sink.csv.unit=minutes

# Polling directory for CsvSink
driver.sink.csv.directory=/Path/at/which/data/will/be/dumped

# Polling period for the CsvSink specific for the worker instance
driver.sink.csv.period=1
# Unit of the polling period for the CsvSink specific for the worker instance
driver.sink.csv.unit=minutes
```

Full Documentation of this you can find in : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics

Comment: what should I use as driver.sink.csv.directory ? since it could not recognize my path: /mnt/metrics-operational/spark-metrics/. What is base directory for emr based jar?

Comment: Since the API is provisioned to write to a local directory. It should recognize the local path. Maybe you have to check the permission of the directory where you are writing. Since you are writing "spark.metrics.conf" in main configuration file that will have the emr jar location.